# Get the ProductID of a woocomerce product in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, product

I am attempting to make some custom functionality in Wordpress and Woocommerce.

I am using ACF to make some custom fields in my Woocommerce products. ACF requires the product ID when finding the fields.

I cannot get the product Id from a product page no matter what I do.

In my functions.php I am trying to at least var_dump out the product id on the product page I am on. This has proved impossible.

I have tried:

```php
 $post_id = get_queried_object_id();

 var_dump($post_id);
```

```php
$apost_id = get_the_ID();

var_dump($apost_id);
```

```php
global $product;
$prodid = $product->get_id();

var_dump($prodid);
```

I either get 0, or bool(false).

I need this ID to be able to use ACF and complete my functionality.

The page slug looks like: https://mywebsite/product/my-product/

Why can I not get my product ID?

I am using WP 6.3.2
I am using Woocommerce 8.2.0

How can I retrieve my product ID for the current page I am on?

Answer (score 0):

The way of getting product ID can be different depending on your snippet and place where you handle your code snippet (For example in different hooks some methods wouldn’t work).

If you do in for single product you just can use `get_the_ID()` method. You can although try to use `global $post` and then `$post->ID`.